# Operator delete associativity

Tags: c++, operators

Whilst looking up operator associativity on wikipedia, I noticed that `delete` has an associativity of right to left. The source is cited as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k(v=vs.120).aspx), I checked it and it comes under group 3 precedence, right to left associativity. So I checked [the C++ standard (n4296)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> **5.3 Unary expressions [expr.unary]**
>
> 1) Expressions with unary operators group right-to-left
>
> ```
> unary-expression:
>     postfix-expression
>     ++ cast-expression
>     -- cast-expression
>     unary-operator cast-expression
>     sizeof unary-expression
>     sizeof ( type-id )
>     sizeof ... ( identifier )
>     alignof ( type-id )
>     noexcept-expression
>     new-expression
>     delete-expression
> unary-operator: one of
>     * & + - ! ~
> ```

What implications does this have? What does `delete` have any associativity at all?

Comment: delete *++x; What if you have a pointer to the pointer before the pointer you want to delete? (stolen from MickLH)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Barry said, precedence is determined by the grammar (and there are a few operators that don't really fit well with the basic idea of precedence so you can only really figure out what happens entirely correctly from the grammar, not a precedence table).

Even if we ignore that, however, the precedence of delete only (at least usually) determines whether a statement is legal/allowed, not what it means. To give a counterexample, with `+` and `*`, precedence determines that `2 * 3 + 4` yields 10 rather than 14 (i.e., multiplication takes precedence).

In the case of `delete`, no value is produced as a result of the `delete` statement, so a statement like `delete x + y;` simply isn't allowed. It would be parsed as `(delete x) + y;`, but since `delete x` doesn't produce a value that can be added to anything else, the result is always prohibited (and if you change the operator, that will remain true).

Associativity doesn't really make sense for `delete`. In particular, associativity deals with whether something like: `a @ b @ c` will be parsed as `(a @ b) @ c` or `a @ (b @ c)` (where `@` is some operator). That's only really meaningful for operators that take two operands though. There's simply no way to combine `delete`s in a way that allows you to ask the question(s) that associativity answers.

Comment: That was what I was thinking; it just doesn't make sense for it to have associativity! I was wondering if I was missing something that gave it a use.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard typically does not define operators in terms of precedence or associativity. It defines them in terms of grammar. From [expr.delete], `delete` is used in a *delete-expression* which is defined as:

> *delete-expression*:
>       ::opt `delete` *cast-expression*
>       ::opt `delete []` *cast-expression*

Where *cast-expression* is defined in [expr.cast]:

> *cast-expression:*
>       *unary-expression*
>        `(` *type-id* `)` *cast-expression*

And *unary-expression* is a whole bunch of things defined [expr.unary], that are all unary expressions (increments, decrements, `delete`s themselves)

That is, `delete *x` is right to-left associative because `(delete (*x))` is the only way to parse that expression according to the grammar.

This is also reason that [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) cites `delete`'s precedence where it does is a direct consequence of that. For example, `delete` is higher than `+` because in an expression like this:

```
delete x+y
```

`x+y` is not a *unary-expression*, so the only legitimate parsing of the grammar would be `(delete x) + y`.

Comment: Precedence is unrelated to associativity.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity is about whether `a op b op c` is parsed as `(a op b) op c` or `a op (b op c)`.

`delete` is a unary operator, so it cannot associate. It has no associativity.

And `delete delete x` is never valid.